# Knockout JS binding on span click not triggering checkbox event

Tags: html, knockout.js

Hi all I have create a sample script which will load news related to Sports, Technology and General. There are 3 check boxes where I am loading respective news on checked. I am expecting the same behavior to be working on clicking respective tags. can some one help me here is the fiddle I am working on

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.news-block {width: 250px;}
</style>
<div id="latest-news">
    <div>
        <h1>News</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="tags">
                <h2>Tagged in:</h2>
                <div class="tags">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="General" id="General-tag-checkbox" data-bind="checked: tags" /><span class="tag General-tag" id="General-tag" >General</span></label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Technology" id="Technology-tag-checkbox" data-bind="checked: tags " /><span class="tag Technology-tag" id="Technology-tag" >Technology</span></label>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Sports" id="Sports-tag-checkbox" data-bind="checked: tags " /><span class="tag Sports-tag" id="Sports-tag" >Sports</span></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="news" data-bind='template: { foreach: articlesToShow, afterMove: afterMove }'>
            <div class="news-block large-3 medium-6 columns">
                <a class="news-item">
                    <div class="news-img">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3><strong data-bind="text: Title"></strong></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="news-content">
                    <p data-bind="text: Excerpt"></p>
                    <p data-bind="text: PublishedDate"></p>
                    <div style="color:red;" class="tags" data-bind='foreach: Categories'>
                        <b><span data-bind="text: $data, attr: {text: $data, class: $data+'-tag'}"></span></b>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $container = $('#news');
    $container.masonry({});

    $("[class$=-tag]").click(function (event) {
        if($(event.target).attr('class').indexOf(' ') >= 0){}
        else{
            var x="#"+$(event.target).attr('class');
            var y=x+"-checkbox";

            if($(y)[0].checked == false){
            }else{
            }
            $(x).click();
        }
    });

    $(".tag").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

var NewsModel = function() {
    this.tags = ko.observableArray([]);
this.newsArticles = ko.observableArray([{
"Title":"General",
"Excerpt":"General",
"PublishedDate":"6 days ago",
 "Categories":["General"]},
 {"Title":"General & Technology",
"Excerpt":"This is both for General and Technology",
"PublishedDate":"3 days ago",
"Categories":["Technology","General"]},
{"Title":"Sports",
 "Excerpt":"This is for Sports",
 "PublishedDate":"3 days ago","Categories":["Sports"]}]);   
this.afterMove = function(element, index, data) {$container.masonry( 'reloadItems' );$container.masonry( 'layout' );};
    this.articlesToShow = ko.computed(function() {
        var desiredArray = this.tags();

        if (_.isEmpty(desiredArray)) return this.newsArticles();

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.newsArticles(), function(newsArticle) {
            return !_.isEmpty(_.intersection(newsArticle.Categories, desiredArray));
        });
    }, this);

};

ko.applyBindings(new NewsModel(), document.getElementById('latest-news'));

</script>
</body>
</html>



 https://jsfiddle.net/eme37hfw/2/
```

Comment: Get rid of the jQuery. Handle your events in Knockout or make custom binding handlers.

Comment: Not much good at Knockout, in learning stage can you help me

Comment: You should create a custom binding for your Masonry related code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594213/auto-apply-masonry-in-knockout-binding-handler-after-dynamic-update